# recursion using a hashmap

Tags: java, recursion, numbers, hashmap, int

I have an array that has the following numbers

```
int[] arr = {2,4,3,1,5,6,0,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
```

Or any other order for that matter.
I need to make all the possible combinations for the numbers using a recursion but satisfying a condition that the next number clubbed with the present one can only be from  specific numbers given by a hashmap:
ex **When the recursion takes 1 the next number can be from {0,4,5,2,6} (from the HaspMap),and then if i make 10,the next number can be from {1,4,5}** and so on

```
static HashMap<Integer,Integer[]> possibleSeq = new HashMap<Integer,Integer[] >();
private static void initialize(HashMap<Integer,Integer[]> possibleSeq) {
    possibleSeq.put(0,new Integer[]{1,4,5});
    possibleSeq.put(1,new Integer[]{0,4,5,2,6});
    possibleSeq.put(2,new Integer[]{1,3,5,6,7});
    possibleSeq.put(3,new Integer[]{2,6,7});
    possibleSeq.put(4,new Integer[]{0,1,5,8,9});
    possibleSeq.put(5,new Integer[]{0,1,2,4,6,8,9,10});
    possibleSeq.put(6,new Integer[]{1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11});
    possibleSeq.put(7,new Integer[]{2,3,6,10,11});
    possibleSeq.put(8,new Integer[]{9,4,5,12,13});
    possibleSeq.put(9,new Integer[]{10,4,5,8,6,12,13,14});
    possibleSeq.put(10,new Integer[]{7,6,5,9,11,15,13,14});
    possibleSeq.put(11,new Integer[]{6,7,10,14,15});
    possibleSeq.put(12,new Integer[]{8,9,13});
    possibleSeq.put(13,new Integer[]{8,9,10,12,14});
    possibleSeq.put(14,new Integer[]{9,10,11,13,15});
    possibleSeq.put(15,new Integer[]{10,11,14});    
}
```

Note: I am required to make all the possible numbers beginning from digit length 1 to 10.
Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like this, for starters:

```
void findPath(Set paths, Stack path, int[] nextSteps, Set numbersLeft) {
    if (numbersLeft.isEmpty()) {
        //Done
        paths.add(new ArrayList(path));
        return;
    }

    for (int step:nextSteps) {
        if (numbersLeft.contains(step)) {
            // We can move on
            path.push(step);
            numbersLeft.remove(step);
            findPath(paths, path, possiblePaths.get(step), numbersLeft);
            numbersLeft.add(path.pop());
        }
    }       
}
```

Starting values should be an empty Set, and empty Stack, a nextSteps identical to you initial array, and a set created from your initial array. When this returns, the paths Set should be filled with the possible paths.

I haven't tested this, and there are bugs as well as more elegant solutions.